# How can i calculate height of a website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to take a snapshot of a website so i have to calculate height of a website. I want to use this value in:

```
Dim MyBrowser As New WebBrowser
MyBrowser.Size = New Size(1027, ???)
```

Thanks...

Comment: are you talking about how to get screen resolution?

Comment: should be "height of a web page":)

Comment: yes, you are right Quamis. i wanted to tell "height of a web page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
Dim docWidth as Integer 
Dim docHeight as Integer

docHeight = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
docWidth = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width
```

Answer (score 0):

when you said height of a website..
did you mean height of a browser window or the the whole document ?

By height of a website if you meant any of the above,
you can take a look into [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) and get the value of height( browser/document) and send that back to server.

Comment: thanks N30 but i prefer "WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height"